# Будет ли диск с файловой системой raid1 работать нормально без второго диска?

Tags: linux, debian

Я купил хост, где имеется два диска каждый по 500гб.
Но эти диски использовались в режиме raid1, в итоге мне было доступно только 500гб.

Но я захотел отказаться от raid1 в пользу дополнительного пространства.
Я отключил второй диск от raid1 такими командами:

```
mdadm --fail /dev/md0 /dev/nvme1n1p1
mdadm --remove /dev/md0 /dev/nvme1n1p1
```

После я на втором диске создал свои разделы ext4, и у меня получилось на хосте 1000 гб.

Сейчас разбивка выглядит так `lsblk`:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p2 259:3    0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0   511M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme0n1p3 259:4    0 444.4G  0 part
  └─md2       9:2    0 444.3G  0 raid1 /
nvme1n1     259:1    0   477G  0 disk
└─nvme1n1p1 259:5    0   477G  0 part  /mnt/tmp
```

Как видно, разделы первого диска остались в файловой с `raid1`.

Вопрос: будет ли первый диск работать нормально в файловой системе `raid1` без второго диска?

Вот что показывает `cat /proc/mdstat`:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md2 : active raid1 nvme0n1p3[0]
      465894720 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 4/4 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 nvme0n1p1[0]
      33520640 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

md1 : active raid1 nvme0n1p2[0]
      523264 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: РАЙД-1 может использовать любое количество зеркалируемых накопителей - в том числе и один (понятно, что в этом случае надёжность будет никакая). Так что работать будет. Но вот наплевать на надёжность, и добывать за её счёт 500 гектар, когда стоимость дополнительного накопителя такой ёмкости 2 тыра - этого я не понимаю...

Comment: так к слову: raid — это не файловая система.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin во всех местах, где обычно пишется имя файловой системы, у меня указано `linux_raid_member` или `Linux raid autodetect`. например, при попытке сделать `mount /dev/nvme1n1p1 /mnt/tmp` выдает `mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'`. честно говоря, я даже не знаю, как узнать, какая в действительности используется файловая система у моих разделов, там где написано `linux_raid_member`

Comment: raid — это технология виртуализации. предоставляет операционной системе виртуальное блочное устройство. как и lvm, например. как «раздел жёсткого диска» — это ж тоже виртуальное блочное устройство, расположенное поверх другого блочного устройства. ключевое свойство файловых систем — предоставление операционной системе набора файлов. ничего из вышеперечисленного (raid, lvm, «разделы») этого не умеют и для этого не предназначены.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если исходить из теории то работать он конечно будет,  а сам факт неисправности будет виден только специальным утилитам управления RAID'ом.
Поэтому в целом можно оставить все как есть, если данные не критичны конечно.